# Wrapper Class Method Parameters

Tags: c#, dll, wrapper

Apologies but this is new to me, I will gladly explain further or edit this post where necessary.

I have a project class library which I need to create a wrapper class library for.   This class contains custom classes for constructors, which are then used as parameters in the methods that I'll be calling from my wrapper.

Within my wrapper I don't really want to have to use a using statement referencing the original class library, so I was wondering what the best way to handle these custom constructors are?

Here is an example I knocked up of what the DLL I'm wrapping looks like:

```
public CustomResult WriteMyDataAndReturnResult(CustomerWriterData data)
{
    CustomerResult result = // Do stuff
    return result;
}


public partial class CustomResult
{
    private int resultId;
    private MyResponse response;

    public int resultIdField
    {
        get { return this.resultId; }
        set { this.resultId = value; }
    }

}

public partial class MyResponse
{
    private string myMessage;

    public string myMessageField
    {
        get { return this.myMessage; }
        set { this.myMessage = value; }
    }
}


public partial class CustomerWriterData
{
    private string outputPath;
    private string inputPath;

    public string myOutputPath
    {
        get { return this.outputPath; }
        set { this.outputPath = value; }
    }
    public string myInputPath
    {
        get { return this.inputPath; }
        set { this.inputPath = value; }
    }
}
```

So in the example above in my wrapper I'd be looking to have a method that calls WriteMyDataAndReturnResult, but this contains a custom object.  What would be the best way to handle things in terms of this?  I have toyed with the idea of recreating each of the partial classes in my wrapper, and then having convert methods to change from one to the other, but this seems like I'd be re-writting a lot of code.

Is there a better way for me to avoid having to include a using statement to the original library within code that calls my wrapper project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it myself by creating a script that mapped the API to my DTO objects.  This wasn't the path I specifically wanted to take, but it at least allowed me to create a separation between the 3rd party API and my main code.